# PHP: Unable to echo variable

Tags: php, variables, xampp, echo, this

I am new to PHP and following is my code:

```
$smartUrl = new SmartUrl('http://www.google.com');
echo $smartUrl->render();

class SmartUrl{
    private $m_baseUrl;

    function __construct($baseUrl){
        $this->m_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
        echo $m_baseUrl;
    }

    public function render(){

        $baseUrl = $this->m_baseUrl;
        return $baseUrl;
    }
}
```

When, I run the above code it gives this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: m_baseUrl in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line
```

I'm assigning a value to `$m_baseUrl` using `$this->m_baseUrl = $baseUrl;` So, why does it not echo the value of `$m_baseUrl`.

If I omit the echo line `echo $m_baseUrl;`, the program works fine.

Can anybody please explain to me why this line `echo $m_baseUrl;`, throws an error?

Comment: You're assigning a value to `$this->m_baseUrl` not `$m_baseUrl`

Comment: you must access member variables with $this inside class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$smartUrl = new SmartUrl('http://www.google.com');
echo $smartUrl->render();

class SmartUrl{
    private $m_baseUrl;

    function __construct($baseUrl){
        $this->m_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
        echo $this->m_baseUrl;//you need access with $this, here $this represent current class
    }

    public function render(){

        $baseUrl = $this->m_baseUrl;
        return $baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `$this`.
`echo $m_baseUrl;`
should be:
`echo $this->m_baseUrl;`